# Transfer Large Files Asynchronously In Flask

Tags: asynchronous, flask, python-3.5, python-asyncio, aiohttp

What is the best approach for transfer large files Asynchronously in Flask? I have read this [article](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask). But I want to know if there is a way to do this without using celery?

Comment: Transfer where? From the client? To the client? To another server?

Comment: @dirnFrom the client to server

Comment: Flask is a synchronous framework, you can try flask+gevent and streaming responses like explained here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/streaming/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask is a synchronous framework, you can try flask+gevent and streaming responses like explained here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/streaming/.

Anyway, if you want to upload properly very large files, I suggest you to use a different approach. Instead of trying to do asynchronous networking with a synchronous framework try delegating the transfer with Nginx upload_module, like explained here: http://blog.thisisfeifan.com/2013/03/nginx-upload-module-vs-flask.html

Nginx is faster and won't load up the files in memory, a thing that regular frameworks like Flask or Django even in Asynchronous mode will do. Remember to configure flask to receive after upload POST with directive `upload_pass`. The only caveat is that you'll have to learn how to compile a full fledge Nginx from source, here an example of working Dockerfile:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie

##### NGINX #####
# Base Stuff
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -qq \
    libssl-dev

# Nginx with upload_module and upload_progress_module
# "Stable version".
ENV ZLIB_VERSION 1.2.11
ENV PCRE_VERSION 8.39
ENV NGX_UPLOAD_MODULE_VERSION 2.2
ENV NGX_UPLOAD_PROGRESS_VERSION 0.9.1
ENV NGX_HEADERS_MORE_VERSION 0.32
ENV NGX_SPPEDPAGE_VERSION 1.11.33.4
ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.11.8

RUN cd /tmp \
    && wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && tar xvf nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && wget https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module/archive/v${NGX_HEADERS_MORE_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzvf v${NGX_HEADERS_MORE_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && wget https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/archive/latest-stable.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzvf latest-stable.tar.gz \
    && wget https://dl.google.com/dl/page-speed/psol/${NGX_SPPEDPAGE_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzvf ${NGX_SPPEDPAGE_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && mv psol ngx_pagespeed-latest-stable/ \
    && git clone -b ${NGX_UPLOAD_MODULE_VERSION} https://github.com/Austinb/nginx-upload-module \
    && wget http://zlib.net/zlib-${ZLIB_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && tar xvf zlib-${ZLIB_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && wget ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/pcre-${PCRE_VERSION}.tar.bz2 \
    && tar -xjf pcre-${PCRE_VERSION}.tar.bz2 \
    && wget https://github.com/masterzen/nginx-upload-progress-module/archive/v${NGX_UPLOAD_PROGRESS_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && tar xvf v${NGX_UPLOAD_PROGRESS_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && cd nginx-${NGINX_VERSION} \
    && ./configure \
    --with-pcre=../pcre-${PCRE_VERSION}/ \
    --with-zlib=../zlib-${ZLIB_VERSION}/ \
    --add-module=../nginx-upload-module \
    --add-module=../nginx-upload-progress-module-${NGX_UPLOAD_PROGRESS_VERSION} \
    --add-module=../ngx_pagespeed-latest-stable \
    --add-module=../headers-more-nginx-module-${NGX_HEADERS_MORE_VERSION} \
    --with-select_module \
    --with-poll_module \
    --with-file-aio \
    --with-http_ssl_module \
    --with-ipv6 \
    --with-pcre-jit \
    --with-http_gzip_static_module \
    --with-http_ssl_module \
    --with-http_v2_module \
    --with-http_realip_module \
    --user=nginx --group=nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-cpu-opt=CPU --    with-ld-opt="-Wl,-E" \
    && make \
   && make install

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**NOTE: Please in this image is lacking the provision of nginx.conf and default.conf.**